# Percentile function in Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, percentile

I know there is a built in function in Jmeter which will give you the responseTime of a sample request. But I wonder if there is something similar for getting different percentile values, like 95th, 99.99th etc, either in JSR223 or Beanshell sampler.

I know its possible to get the value in the HTML report but I want to know if you can get it from some built in method?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no "built-in" methods, if you need this information in JMeter runtime you can configure JMeter to immediately write the interim results into the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) by [setting the following JMeter property:](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
```

Then you can read the .jtl file in Groovy and perform the calculation as per your requirements, something like:

```
def lines = new File('result.jtl').readLines()
def linesWithoutHeader = lines.subList(1, lines.size())

def elapsed = []

linesWithoutHeader.each { line ->
    elapsed.add(line.split(',')[1] as long)
}

elapsed = elapsed.sort()
def index = Math.ceil(99 / 100.0 * elapsed.size()) as int
log.info('99 percentile: ' + elapsed.get(index - 1))
```

will give you the 99 percentile in the [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging).